# Modify root password on MacOS X

Tags: macos, passwords, root, reset

On a Mac I do not have the root password, but I have a user with administrative privileges.
Can I use it to reset the root password?

Thank's.

MacOS X 10.6.3

Answer (score 3):

Are you sure your installation of OS X has a root user? It's [disabled by default](http://support.apple.com/kb/ht1528), and to run a command with root privileges the administrative user would use [`sudo`](http://gemma.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man8/sudo.8.html) instead, using their own password (which [cannot be blank](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT4103)).

Answer (score 1):

Should it not be:
    sudo passwd root

Alternatively, you can follow these instructions on recovering a root password on Mac OS X: [link text](http://www.macosxhints.com/article.php?story=20001217230925152).